# Apply discount after getting Total in magento

Tags: magento, discount

Can anyone elaborate working of discount applying to whole cart.I Could not get the logic behind it.Actually i do want to write my own custom discount applying to cart.

Currently i am overriding Mage/salesrules and adding my rules in validator.php.It works but the problem is discount is getting applied for every item.I tried to understand the logic behind fixed cart rule but i couldnt.Is there any other way i can  do it.

As i am new to magento and php or ecommerce as whole.give me it elaborately...please

Comment: which type of discount you want to use and please little elaborate your question to understand propely

Comment: @RohitGoel In magento promotion rules there is a dropdown for different type of promotion like Buy X get y free,fixed amount discount.What i want to do is my rule comes under that so that i can get the discount amount no of uses from there itself.But my problem is that process functions is called for every item.I want to apply the discount to whole cart not single item?...if its seems silly sorry i am a newbie in developing

Comment: we can create a rule in the admin for total cart amount total, like if the cart total is greater than 100 than you can give a discount according to your need

Answer (score 0):

You can set discount rules and such based on the total amount of the order. This can be done in promotion -> shopping cart price rules. Why not use that?